# One Mysql Query to get top rated rooms based on weight

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "rooms" that has "id" col, and "visits" that contains the rows "rid" (room id), "rating" (goes from 0 to 10).

I'd like to get top rooms **ignoring** votes of 0, based on weighted rating, like this formula:

> ((total_avg_votes * total_avg_rating) + (specific_votes * specific_avg_rating)) / (total_avg_votes + speicific_votes)

I have this formula but it won't get me the rating as well, also not ignoring votes of 0:

```
SELECT rooms.id, t1.count FROM rooms INNER JOIN ( SELECT rid, COUNT(rating) as count
FROM
   visits
WHERE visits.rating <> 0
GROUP BY visits.rid) AS t1 ON rooms.id = t1.rid
```

Comment: `ORDER BY t1.sum/t1.count DESC`

Comment: Hi, edited question to be more detailed and specific.

Comment: Post sample data and expected output.

Comment: I just want to get all rooms ids and their ranking (ordered by highest to lowest).